# So long and thanks for all the fish

Tags: discussion, moderators

Over the last year or so my activity here has [dropped off](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50/ire-and-curses?tab=activity), for a number of (predictable) reasons. It's been a long time coming, but I wanted to let you all know that I will be stepping down imminently as one of your moderators here at Board & Card Games. I started moderating here [over five years ago](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), and it's time for a change.

It has been an honour to serve this community as a founding member and moderator, and it will always be something I remember with pleasure and pride. The site continues to go strong and I am sure the future is bright. I hope to still see you around occasionally, certainly the next time I have an ambiguous rule to clarify!

Take it easy. May all your dice rolls be sixes, your opponents be cursed with the wrong colour mana, and your available resources exactly match your intentions!

ire_and_curses

Comment: Thanks for the 5+ years, and hope you have time to play enough games that we'll see you again for a question or two eventually!

Comment: Thanks for everything!

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm sure I'll be around. :)

Comment: Thanks very much, it's been good having you as a moderator. I love your sign-off line. Take care. :)