# New Moderator Pro Tem Announcement 2017

Tags: discussion, moderators

As some of you may have [read](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1557/12248), [ire_and_curses](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/50/ire-and-curses) has stepped down from their position as Pro Tem moderator. Since we still don't have an estimate for when this site will be fully graduated and able to host its first elections, a replacement for the position left open was in order. **Let's all thank ire_and_curses for the time (over 5 years!) and effort they've put into this community!**

And I am pleased to announce that Jefromi has stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed, and to continue to help the site grow into a huge success.

[image: Jefromi]

Please welcome Jefromi for the hard work and time they contribute.

You can read about the Pro-Tem Moderator program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **there'll be elections once the site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Very happy to be here to help out! And that "their" and "they" made my day, thank you :)

Comment: Congratulations Jefromi. The site is in capable hands. :)

Comment: "There'll be elections once the site has graduated". So that will be, what, another 6 years? At any rate, glad that Jefromi is stepping up in the mean time!

Comment: @Thunderforge I suppose if we want graduation, we can all do our part by playing more games and asking more questions!